# Problemas al Compilar en Codeblocks

Tags: codeblocks

Acabo de instalar el Fedora 25 en mi maquina.
Descargué Codeblocks desde la terminal y lo primero que hice fue un Hola mundo en C++, el programa compila, pero cuando lo ejecuto me aparece un mensaje que dice que el programa no está compilado. Hay soluciones para este problema pero para Windows, hasta ahora no he encontrado ninguna para Linux.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. Si no es mucha molestia, ¿ podrias indicar los pasos exactos que realizas ? como compilas, como ejecutas, texto de error **exacto** que obtienes, ... En fin, cualquier *cosilla* que pudiera ser relevante.

Comment: Debe ser algún proceso que elimina software malicioso, y por eso no ejecuta. Te recomiendo compilar algo más complejo que un _Hola Mundo._.